# I have error when i run "cordova run android"

Tags: firebase, cordova-plugins, angular7, ionic4, cordova-admob

I have the problem below when i run "ionic cordova run android" or when i build android, can same one help me plz.

When i run "cordova run android" i have this error, help me please.

> BUILD FAILED in 7s
>       3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
>       /Users/mac/Desktop/Projets/Magazine Anissati/anissatiapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with
>   exit code 1 Error output:
>       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date
> ```
>
> check.
>
> > In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0.
> >           4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> ```
>   Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.0.4 ->
> ```
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basemen
>         t@[11.0.4], but play-services-basement version was 17.0.0.
>
> ```
>   The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
>   ifact with the issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass@11.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet@11.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector@18.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@11.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@19.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@18.1.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-abt@18.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@18.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@18.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@11.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@11.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@18.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@18.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@19.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype@17.0.0
>
>   For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
>   endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
>   uild.gradle file.
> ```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? I'm stuck in the same issue :/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a common build error.

You need a special plugin which will override the play services version so that everyone asks for the same version.

This plugin will provide that functionality:

[appfeel/cordova-play-services-version-adapter: Cordova/Ionic Google Play Services Versions Incompatibility Adapter](https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-play-services-version-adapter)

To use it just type this into the console:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-play-services-version-adapter
```

Comment: Hello @rtpHarry and thank tou for you answer, i install the plugin but i had i new error :

Comment: 'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible:
You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':
    - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+'

Comment: It's polite to upvote when somebody helps. I'm spending time to build my rep here. Another plugin that I've used in a similar scenario is [this one](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) which lets you force a google play services version. Looking at your error message it seems thats what this plugin is failing to update. Other options are to ensure you have the latest versions of all plugins installed and then manually editing the gradle file where it requests a version that conflicts.